# Description not saving when using summernote

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to create a page that when you click on the create product button
a modal pops up and then you enter whatever you like.

I'm using summernote as my WYSIWYG editor and I'm also using vue as my frontend.

The problem I'm having is that my description isn't being saved.

In my layouts.app I have summernote's cdn.

Here is my code

My Create.vue

```
<template>
    <transition name="modal-fade">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>
            <div class="modal" style="display: inline;">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document" style="width: 680px; max-width: 680px;">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">Create Product</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" @click="close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div>
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="mt-2">
                                <label>Description</label>
                                <textarea id="summernote" v-model="description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="close">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="save">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [],
        data() {
            return {
                name: null,
                description: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.$emit('close');
            },
            save() {
                var description = document.getElementById("summernote").value;

                axios.post('/admin/products', {
                    name: this.name,
                    description: description,
                }).then((response) => {

                });
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            $('#summernote').summernote();
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .modal-fade-enter,
    .modal-fade-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .modal-fade-enter-active,
    .modal-fade-leave-active {
        transition: opacity .25s ease
```

Comment: Hi, In which description the value is not being saved, in data > description or in var description in the save method?

Comment: where are you importing Axios? you can either import Axios or use $axios helper if you have setup accordingly

Comment: @YashMaheshwari - it isn't being saved with both. I've tried the data > description and the var description

Comment: @LakhveerBawa - I'm using laravel with vue so the axios is being imported in the app.js

Comment: ahh, ok, are you getting any error in the console or network tab in developer tools?

Comment: @Aurilie Try changing `description: null` in data to `description: ''`, as defining a variable will treat it a object.

Comment: @LakhveerBawa - I get this error `"SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"description\" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: @YashMaheshwari - I tried that and when I console it out it doesn't display anything

Comment: @Aurilie As your error looks like, it is not front-end issue, in my opinion.

Comment: @Aurilie it is a schema issue actually, you have to change the schema and make the description column Nullable.

In your migration file, you would do something like this

$table->text('description', 500)->nullable();